# Trying to set MaskRe to accept space?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using MaskRe `/[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-]/`. User can enter Numbers, Alphabets , Slash, Dot and Hyphen. How can i add space to this?

I just tried `/[a-zA-Z0-9\/.-s]/`, But its not accepting space.

Also tried `/[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/`, here space is working. How can i add "/-" to this?

Finally, I used `/[a-zA-Z0-9\s-//]+$/`.
it is working, but in eclipse showing syntax error.
Also its not working in IE.

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\/]+$/
```

Your regexp has error at -//, you didn't escape it.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Its working in my application. But In eclipse its showing the error mentioned below. "Multiple markers at this line 1.Syntax error on token '/', Exception expected after this token 2.Syntax error, insert '}' to complete ArrayLiteralElement".

Comment: Try to use RegExp constructor `new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\.\\/]+$')`.

Comment: Hyphen no more needed? `new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9\\s\\.\\/-]+$')`